# Map Function for Numpy Matrix

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I have two numpy matrices. One contains lambda functions. The other contains values.

Is there a function that is similar to Python's map function that will allow me to get the expected result?

Is there a better way?

```
functionMatrix = np.array([[lambda x:x**2, lambda x:x**3],[lambda x: x**2, 
lambda x: np.sqrt(x)]])
valueMatrix = np.array([[1,2],[3,4]])

expectedResult = np.array([[1,8],[9,2]])
```

Comment: If it's always simple exponents you're trying to get, you could just avoid the lambdas, and do something like : `functionMatrix = np.array([[2, 3],[2, 0.5]])` and then `valueMatrix ** functionMatrix` (output: `array([[ 1.,  8.], [ 9.,  2.]])`). Also, judging by your expected output, I think you mean `lambda x: x**2` instead of `lambda x: x*2`, and `np.sqrt` instead of `np.square`

Comment: sacul - You're right, let me fix that.
It won't always be simple exponents. Some functions might be natural log, inverse, etc.

Comment: "is there a better way?" depends on if there's a mathematical relationship to all your lambda functions. Putting them inside a numpy array nets you an 'object array' which is a convenience feature built into numpy, but it does not take advantage of many of the benefits of a normal array (from a speed or memory standpoint).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is just syntactic sugar but does the job.

```
@np.vectorize
def apply_vec(f, x):
    return f(x)

result = apply_vec(functionMatrix, valueMatrix)
```